# Markdown Pandoc: How to set headings to sans font and paragraphs to serif font

Tags: pandoc, markdown

How to set pandoc to generate pdf from markdown file to use sans font for heading and serif font for paragraphs? Do I need to put something to yaml header?

I want this:

[image: Previes]

I'm just using `pandoc file.md -o file.pdf` but it produces entire text in serif font (headings and paragraphs are serif), that's not what I want.

This is my yaml header:

```
---
geometry: margin=2cm
output: pdf_document
lang: cs
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this ist to use `KOMA-Script`by loading the documentclass `scrartcl`:

```
---
documentclass: scrartcl
geometry: margin=2cm
output: pdf_document
lang: cs
---

# First

Text

## Second

Text
```

[image]